# Cleaning up repetitive Material UI tags

Tags: reactjs, refactoring, material-ui

I'm building a resume using React and Material UI. I'm starting to end up with lots of grids with list items that contain different information. I'm wondering if a loop taking in data from an array or object will work in my case and the best way to approach it

Basically this code repeats itself 4 or 5 times, but it all contains different data. I thought about using a loop but the first Grid item size is xs={4} and the grid horizontal to it has a size of xs={8} but with no icon.

```
<Grid item xs={4}>
  <List>
    <ListItem>        
      <ListItemIcon >
        <School className={classes.icon}/>
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText 
        primary={
          <React.Fragment>
            <Typography className = {classes.school} variant="body1">
              The name of the school I attended goes here
            </Typography>
          </React.Fragment>
        }
        secondary="Year I attended this school"
      />
    </ListItem>
  </List>
</Grid>

<Grid item xs={8}>
  <List>
    <ListItem>        
      <ListItemText 
        primary={
          <React.Fragment>
            <Typography className = {classes.school} variant="body1">
              The certificate I received from that school goes here
            </Typography>
          </React.Fragment>
        }
        secondary="The subjects I completed as part of this certificate"   
      />
    </ListItem>
  </List>
</Grid>
```

Looks like this in the browser:

```
<Icon> School 1                           Web Dev Certificate
2019                                      Topics: ...

<Icon> School 2                           Web Dev2 Certificate
2018                                      Topics: ...

<Icon> School 3                           Web Dev3 Certificate
2018                                      Topics: ...

<Icon> School 4                           Web Dev4 Certificate
2017                                      Topics: ...

<Icon> School 5                           Web Dev5 Certificate
2017                                      Topics: ...
```

I want to cut down on all these repetitive code, if possible.

Comment: You can make `ListItemText` block into a new component and pass `props`.

Comment: Any chance you could post an example of what you mean? I'm fairly new at this stuff. Wouldn't I need to create an object or array of all my information and pull from that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `props` for that. First, create a component using the code that will be repeated:

```
function RepeatingComponent(props) {
  return (
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <List>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon >
            <School className={classes.icon} />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText
            primary={
              <React.Fragment>
                <Typography className={classes.school} variant="body1">
                  {props.nameOftheSchool} // props
            </Typography>
              </React.Fragment>
            }
            secondary={props.yearAttended} //props
          />
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </Grid>

    <Grid item xs={8}>
      <List>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemText
            primary={
              <React.Fragment>
                <Typography className={classes.school} variant="body1">
                  {props.theCertificate} // props
            </Typography>
              </React.Fragment>
            }
            secondary={props.theSubject} // props
          />
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default RepeatingComponent;
```

And then you need a component that will call all those `RepeatingComponent` and render then passing props:

```
import RepeatingComponent from 'path_to_component'

function ComponentToRender(props) {
  return (
    <Fragment> // every React component has to be inside of only one tag, the Fragments does nothing to the code, just hold other tags
      <RepeatingComponent nameOftheSchool="name1" yearAttended="year1" theCertificate="certificate1" theSubject="subj1" />
      <RepeatingComponent nameOftheSchool="name2" yearAttended="year2" theCertificate="certificate2" theSubject="subj2" />
      <RepeatingComponent nameOftheSchool="name3" yearAttended="year3" theCertificate="certificate3" theSubject="subj3" />
    // ... as many as you want
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

You can even organize then in a `.json` and use a map to create those component tags and reduce the code duplication even more